# Styled-components Import Cycling

Tags: reactjs, styled-components, styling

I would like to know if using import cycling for styled-components is acceptable?

I know that import cycling is overall forbidden, but in a case where I would only import types and styles would it be fine? Or there could be some downsides?

example:

-index.ts

```
import styled from 'styled-components'

export * from './Header'

export type HeaderProps = {
  example: any
}

export const HeaderContainer = styled.div`
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
`
```

-Header.tsx:

```
import React from 'react'

import * as S from '.'

export const Header: React.FC<S.HeaderProps> = ({ example }) => {
  return (
    <S.HeaderContainer>
      <p>123</p>
    </S.HeaderContainer>
  )
}
```